# How do you get alternatingItemColors to work properly in spark MXDataGridItemRenderer?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm trying to set the alternatingItemColors for a custom MXDataGridItemRenderer and nothing seems to work. I've tried every combination of setting the property that I can think of, from the application, to the dataGrid, to the renderer, with every combination of autoDrawBackground set to true or false with no luck. Ultimately, I'm looking to use the custom itemRenderer, which has a set of semi-transparent  primitives behind the label, with the alternatingItemColors to make the rows easier to read, but keep the style of the custom renderer intact. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
~Benny

Okay, I'm not used to the formatting, and posting replies and so forth, but I'm just going to append the original post, hopefully that works okay for everyone...

So, again, the ItemRenderer:

```
<s:MXDataGridItemRenderer 
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
focusEnabled="true"
minWidth="25" minHeight="25"
>
<!--- States -->
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="hovered" />
    <s:State name="selected"/>
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>
<!--- TransparencyGroup_(=(--> 
<s:Group
    top="0" right="0" bottom="0" left="0"
    alpha="0.7"
    >
    <!--- BaseRectOuter -->
    <s:Rect
        radiusX="5" radiusY="5"
        top="0" right="0" bottom="0" left="0"
        >
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry
                    color="0x333333"
                    />
                <s:GradientEntry
                    color="0x121212"
                    />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <!--- BaseRectInner -->
    <s:Rect
        radiusX="5" radiusY="5"
        top="1" right="0" bottom="1" left="0"
        >
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry
                    color="0x222222"
                    />
                <s:GradientEntry
                    color="0x444444"
                    />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <!--- InnerRect -->
    <s:Rect
        radiusX="4" radiusY="4"
        top="2" right="2" bottom="2" left="2"
        >
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry
                    color="0x000"
                    color.hovered="0x105562"
                    />
                <s:GradientEntry
                    color="0x333333"
                    color.selected="0x105562"
                    />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <!--- InnerStroke -->
    <s:Rect
        radiusX="4" radiusY="4"
        top="1" right="2" bottom="1" left="2"   
        >
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry
                    color="0x000"
                    color.selected="0xCCCDDD"
                    />
                <s:GradientEntry
                    color="0x666666"
                    color.selected="0x000"
                    alpha="0.6"
                    />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>
</s:Group>
<!--- _)=)-->
<!--- Label -->
<s:Label 
    id="lblData"
    text="{dataGridListData.label}"
    fontSize="12"
    color="0xFFFFFC"
    height="12"
    left="12" right="12"
    trackingLeft="20%"
    verticalCenter="0"
    mouseEnabled="false"
    />
</s:MXDataGridItemRenderer>
```

And here's the DataGrid:

```
<mx:DataGrid 
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
rowHeight="30"
headerHeight="30"
fontFamily="Times New Roman" 
fontSize="14"
textAlign="center"
paddingTop="2" paddingRight="0"
paddingBottom="2" paddingLeft="0"
verticalScrollPolicy="auto"
borderVisible="false"
dropShadowVisible="false"
rollOverColor="#01292B" 
selectionColor="#000000"
chromeColor="#1D3A40"
alternatingItemColors="#FFFFFF, #000000"
>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import b_renderers.DGR_NameCol_01;
        import b_renderers.DGItemRenderer_02;
        import b_renderers.HeaderRenderer_01;
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:columns>
    <mx:DataGridColumn
        itemRenderer="b_renderers.DGR_NameCol_01"
        headerRenderer="b_renderers.HeaderRenderer_01"
        headerText="(|_ Name _|)"
        dataField="name"
        sortable="false"
        width="285"
        />
    <mx:DataGridColumn
        itemRenderer="b_renderers.DGItemRenderer_02"
        headerRenderer="b_renderers.HeaderRenderer_01"
        headerText="Time"
        dataField="time"
        width="65"
        />
    <mx:DataGridColumn
        itemRenderer="b_renderers.DGItemRenderer_02"
        headerRenderer="b_renderers.HeaderRenderer_01"
        headerText="-| Genre |-"
        dataField="genre"
        width="165"
        />
</mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: How about you share some code for your itemRenderer, and possibly the DataGrid.

Comment: Here's the ItemRenderer:

Comment: Woops, let me try this again...

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit late, since this is a three month old post, but if you are still looking for an answer...it looks like this might be the problem:

`alternatingItemColors="#FFFFFF, #000000"`

should be:

`alternatingItemColors="[#FFFFFF, #000000]"`

Comment: Hey, better late than never; Thanks!]